# What is the canonical method for removing a unit/service file from systemd?

Tags: systemd

What is the systemd-approved method for removing e.g. sidekiq.service from `/etc/systemd/system/`?

Note, there are many related discussions on this topic such as this one which I have already read:
https://superuser.com/questions/513159/how-to-remove-systemd-services

My point of confusion is that the most-accepted answer in the above discussion requires the user to manually `rm` files from a bunch of locations, but a later answer suggests that `systemctl disable <service>` should have the same effect as manually removing the files.

According to my own testing of `systemctl disable sidekiq`, I am finding that the unit file `sidekiq.service` remains at `/etc/systemd/system` afterwards.

I understand that, in theory, using `rm` on a bunch of locations should do the trick, but I'm wondering how someone who is actually familiar with `systemd` or `systemctl` would do this. Is such brute force really necessary, or is there an actual `systemctl` command for this purpose?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm trying to remove artifacts of my sidekiq installation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to uninstall software, then removing the file is the correct approach. But remember that systemd will remember the service until told to reload its configuration with `systemctl daemon-reload`. Then it will notice the unit is gone, and (if the service isn't still running) forget about it.

Comment: I was trying to `disable` a service, but it was still showing up even after `daemon-reload`. Turns out I was forgetting to use `disable --now`, so `systemd` was still hanging onto it because it was running. You're line "if the service isn't still running" was the hint I needed. Thanks!